# Where does PersistStoreWrite (BaseBackend x) constraint come from when using generic Persistent?

Tags: haskell, persistent

While toying around with `persistent`, I can't figure out where does the `PersistStoreWrite (BaseBackend b)` constraint come from. I can't see it on the signature of [`insert`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.12/persistent-2.6/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:insert).

```
x :: (
    MonadIO m,
    PersistStoreRead b,
    PersistStoreWrite b,
    PersistStoreWrite (BaseBackend b)      -- <--- where does this come from?
    ) => ReaderT b m ()
x = do
    now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
    aTaskId <- insert (TaskItem "Hello" now)
    aTask <- get aTaskId
    liftIO (print aTask)
```

The above works fine, but if I remove the mentioned constraint, the compiler complains ("arising from a use of `insert`"). 
I'm using stack with lts-7.12 resolver (GHC 8, persistent 2.6).

Data definition for the record:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings{mpsGeneric = True}, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
TaskItem
    name Text
    submittedAt UTCTime
    deriving Show
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strange thing was, also the `get` method required the `BaseBackend` write. As hinted by @snoyman, this is partly due to the generated TH code. Part of the TH-generated splice:

```
instance PersistStore backend =>
         PersistEntity (TaskItemGeneric backend) where
    type PersistEntityBackend (TaskItemGeneric backend) = backend
```

Note that `PersistStore` is an alias to `PersistStoreWrite`. This, in combination with the constraint `PersistRecordBackend record backend` on the `get` method of `PersistStoreRead`, which expands to:

```
type PersistRecordBackend record backend =
    (PersistEntity record, PersistEntityBackend record ~ BaseBackend backend)
```

indeed results in the inferred constraint `PersistStoreWrite (BaseBackend backend)`.

**Solution**

In fact this is trivial - a sensible `BaseBackend` should always support writes. So I just added aliases for the constraints:

```
type PersistRead b = (PersistStoreRead b, PersistStoreWrite (BaseBackend b))
type PersistWrite b = (PersistRead b, PersistStoreWrite b)
```

so

```
x :: (MonadIO m, PersistWrite b) => ReaderT b m ()
x = do
    now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
    aTaskId <- insert (TaskItem "Hello" now)
    aTask <- get aTaskId
    liftIO (print aTask)
```